# Почему textImeMultiLine не мультистрочный?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

Мне нужно изменить на клавиатуре кнопку и привязать слушатель, обычный `multiline` не меняет, а c `textImeMultiLine` все хорошо, но почему текст на новую строчку не перемещается. Почему?

Xml:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:imeActionId="1"
        android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
```

Java код:

```
text_input = findViewById(R.id.input_text);
text_input.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "IME_ACTION_DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

            return false;

}
```

Comment: Покажите настройки поля в вода. Программные и в разметке

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Как вы и просили , добавил xml и java код.

Comment: Т.е. вам надо и поменять кнопку так, чтобы она выглядела не как Enter, но работала как он и ещё и её нажатия отслеживать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не совсем. Обычный multiline автоматически переводит курсор, когда доходит до края строки, мне нужно что бы это работало, но при этом была изменена кнопка и отслеживалось её нажатие. А textImeMultiLine просто продолжает дальше писать, даже если строка на экране уже закончилась, тебе приходиться скроллить по горизонтале.

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022589/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб О боже... А так работает....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решить проблему можно таким образом:

Use

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

and in XML:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022589/3212712